# cross-correlation inequality

Tags: correlation

Show that

$$
|R_{XY}(\tau)| \le \frac{1}{2}\left[R_X(0) + R_Y(0)\right]
$$

I tried use Schwarz's inequality.
$$
E^2\{zw\} \le E\{z^2\}E\{w^2\} 
$$

where z is $z=X(t+\tau)$ and w is $w=X(t+\tau)-Y(t)$. Doing the math, the result was
$$
R_{XY}(\tau) \le \sqrt{R_X(0)R_Y(0)}
$$
That result is given in many books, but it does not solve my problem. If anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Comment: next use the AM-GM inequality

Comment: $\sqrt{ab}\leq \frac{1}{2}(a+b)$ for $a,b\geq0$. A simple way to check this is though expanding  the binomial formula $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2\geq0$